# C++/CLI: Passing C++ class ptr to unmanaged method

Tags: c++-cli, pointers

I've been given a third party C/C++ library (.dll, .lib, .exp and .h) that I need to use in our C# app.

ThirdPartyLibrary.h contains...

```
class AClass {
 public:
  typedef enum {
      green = 7,
      blue = 16
  } Color;
  virtual int GetData()=0;
  virtual int DoWork(Color, char *)=0;
};

void * Func1(int, AClass **aClass);
```

In my C++/CLI code I have done this...

```
#include "ThirdPartyLibrary.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace Wrapper {
public ref class MyBridgeClass
{
private:
  AClass* pAClass;

public:
  // C# code will call this method
  void AMethod (int x)
  {
    int y = x+10;
    Func1 (y, &(this->pAClass));  // <-- error!
  }
}
}
```

I get a build error that reads...

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'AClass **'
      with
      [
          Type=AClass *
      ]
      Cannot convert a managed type to an unmanaged type
```

Any ideas?  Maybe I need #pragma manage/unmanged tags in my C++/CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because of how managed memory works.

In your managed class, you've got a pointer defined. The address of that pointer is part of the managed object, and can change when the garbage collector runs. That's why you can't just pass `&pAClass` to the method, the GC can change what that address actually is.

There's a couple things you can do to fix this:

You could create an unmanaged helper class to hold the `AClass*` member. I'd do this if that pointer needs to stay valid beyond the invocation of this method, or if you have a lot of unmanaged pointers to hold.

```
struct UnmanagedHolder
{
    AClass* pAClass;
};

public ref class MyBridgeClass
{
private:
  // must create in constructor, delete in destructor and finalizer.
  UnmanagedHolder* unmanaged; 

public:
  // C# code will call this method
  void AMethod (int x)
  {
    int y = x+10;
    Func1 (y, &(this->unmanaged->pAClass));
  }
};
```

If you only need the pointer to be valid within AMethod, and the pointer doesn't need to remain valid after the call to Func1, then you can use a pin_ptr.

```
void AMethod (int x)
{
  int y = x+10;
  pin_ptr<AClass*> pin = &(this->pAClass);
  Func1 (y, pin);
}
```

Comment: I knew about pinning, but I didn't realize that unmanaged fields were still allocated on the Managed Heap.  I added a 'this->unmanaged = new UnmanagedHolder ()' to the bridge class' ctor and a 'if (this->unmanged) delete this->unmanged' to the bridge class' finalizer.